# SQL Restrict Column values using another Table

Tags: sql, key

Im new to SQL, and am using SQL Server Managmetn Studio V11

Im having trouble with my structure:

for example if I have a Table **Fruit**:

> FruitID, Name , FamilyID, ColourID

Table **Family**

> FamilyID, Name

Table **AllowedColour**

```
ID, FamilyID, ColourID
1,     1,     56
2,     1,     88
3,     1,     99
4,     2,     56
5,     2,     57
```

So in `Allowed Colour` I list the Colours that a certain family can have.
How do I restrict the values entered in the `Fruit` table so that only Allowed colours can be given to the fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique constraint to AllowedColors. (And consider dropping the column "ID".)

```
alter table AllowedColors
add constraint your_constraint_name
unique (FamilyID, ColorID);
```

You *probably* want each of those columns to be declared `NOT NULL`, too. I'll leave that to you.

Now you can use that pair of columns as the target of a foreign key constraint.

```
alter table fruit
add constraint another_constraint_name
foreign key (FamilyID, ColorID) 
  references AllowedColors (FamilyID, ColorID);
```

You'll also want a foreign key from AllowedColors.FamilyID to Family.FamilyID.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This has helped me very much, I didnt realise I could use a Unqiue Constraint in that way

Comment: If you drop the column "ID", you can declare {FamilyID, ColorID} the primary key instead of declaring them unique. Everything else will work the same.

Comment: Is this method suitable to build a "dictionary" of valid values or value combinations in practice?

Comment: @AurusHuang: I'm not sure what you mean. In a SQL dbms, valid values are usually stored in a table; other table set a foreign key reference to that table. [See this dba.stackexchange answer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9065/1064) Is that what you're thinking about?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' That's exactly what I want! Thank you.

Comment: Foreign key requires either unique or primary key constraint. What if we want to limit to a non-key column with repetitive values? (Just to make sure data will be valid)

Comment: @Saleh: To validate data, create a table of valid values, and set a foreign key reference to that table. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17379201/562459), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8996345/562459), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604737/562459).